# delete a row from a list

Tags: c#

i have a form with 6 textboxes and a delete button.that i want to do is to read a text file and save it into  a list.after that i want to give a value at the textbox1 and delete the row from the list that this value exists.with this code(i have already done) delete all the values from the text file.what should i change to the code?i use Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.

```
   List<string> StoreItems;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       filePath = @"C:\Users\v\Desktop\text.txt";

       StoreItems = new List<string>();
   }



  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                StoreItems.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.Default))
        {
            foreach (string line in StoreItems)
            {
                if(line == textBox1.Text)//remove all from the list
                StoreItems.Remove(line);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx).

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

There's no need for explicit iteration over the list. You can just call it like this:

```
StoreItems.RemoveAll(item => item == textBox1.Text);
```

You also forgot to write the list back to the file. I think you want code like this:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
{
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        StoreItems.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
    }
}

StoreItems.RemoveAll(item => item == textBox1.Text);
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.Default))
{
    foreach (string line in StoreItems)
    {
        streamWrite.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i use removeall,delete all the text in my file and not only one row.why?

Comment: When I use RemoveAll it behaves exactly as documented. I guess you've got a simple mistake in your code.

Comment: Don't put `RemoveAll` in a loop. Get rid of that loop. `RemoveAll` removes all items that match the condition passed to it. Also, you have forgotten to write to the file. Bear with me and I'll update my answer to help you.

Comment: OK, I think my update should get you home. I also reverted your question to its original form. If you want to add some extra code then do so but do it as an addition, and only that code that is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default)) 
    { 
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) 
        { 
            StoreItems.Add(streamReader.ReadLine()); 
        } 
    } 


int i = StoreItems.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
while (i >= 0) 
{
    StoreItems.RemoveAt(i);
    i = StoreItems.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: This could get quite expensive with multiple iterations over the list. Either use RemoveAll (by far the simplest) or at the very least iterate once only.